# Spring cloud stream project, kafka DLQ configuration is ignored for Leyton version

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I did some experiments with spring cloud streaming where kafka is data source.
It was required to configure `dlq` and my configuration don't support it.
So I switched on [open source example](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/main/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-dlq-sample/src/main/resources/application.yml) and it really works.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder:
  configuration:
    commit.interval.ms: 1000
    default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$IntegerSerde
    application.id: dlq-demo-sample
  serdeError: sendToDlq
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process-out-0:
  destination: counts
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process-in-0:
  destination: words
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-in-0.consumer:
  dlqName: words-count-dlq
  valueSerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$IntegerSerde
```

The example uses `<spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>`
and

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

I upgraded this libraries to newer versions: `<spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>` and

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

After updating versions the usual scenario works as expected (in case the value serde is `StringSerde`), but DLQ configuration ignored (using original `yml`).

Do you think that I updated example to incompatible libraries?

...following [spring documentation](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud) its should be compatible:

```
|Release Train       | Spring Boot Generation |
|---------------------------------------------|
|2023.0.x aka Leyton | 3.2.x                  |
...
```

Do you think I missed some important properties to make it working with newer spring versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serde-error` in your configuration (`serdeError: sendToDlq`) has been deprecated for a while and removed from the binder in the `4.0.x` version. This is in favor of `deserialization-exception-handler`. See the ref docs for details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/kafka/kafka-streams-binder/error-handling.html

Can you use that new property and try again? We will update the sample you referenced above to reflect the new configuration.

Comment: It works for me. Thanks for answer. Possible you could advice how to make `dlq` working not only for `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams` but for simplyer solution like `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka` or on which part i should pay my attention to debug solution for `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka` case?

Comment: Is something not working for you with DLQ and the regular Kafka binder? It might be better if you could start a new question on that matter rather than here. Thanks.

Comment: i've just collected details for a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78107151/5728095)