# Spring cloud stream kafka binder, no messages in DLQ topic for Leyton version

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

### Service details

To construct my example I've used

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

and

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2023.0.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```

to build stream I've used

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

My `yml` configuration is

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: report
    stream:
      bindings:
        report-in-0:
          destination: ${kafka-conf.consume-topic-report}
          group: ${kafka-conf.group}-report-78107151
          consumer:
            enableDlq: true
            dlqName: ${kafka-conf.report-dlq}
        report-out-0:
          destination: ${kafka-conf.produce-topic-report}
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: ${kafka-conf.server}
          schemaRegistryUrl: ${kafka-conf.schema}
        default:
          producer:
            configuration:
              schema.registry.url: ${kafka-conf.schema}
              key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
              value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
              value.subject.name.strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy
          consumer:
            configuration:
              schema.registry.url: ${kafka-conf.schema}
              key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
              value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
              value.subject.name.strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy
              specific.avro.reader: true
        bindings:
          report-in-0:
            consumer:
              configuration:
                value.deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
                spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
                specific.avro.reader: true
```

### Expectations

If stream gets correct message

- it should be processed;
- the processed result should be published to `report_topic_redirect`;
- no errors;

If stream gets incorrect message

- log error;
- send corrupted message to `DLQ` topic (in provided configuration it's `report_dlq`);
- no blocking for next messages;

### Inconsistency of the result with expectations

- no published messages in the `DLQ` topic (`report_dlq`)

### Question

It seems I've correctly configured the error handler (because after logging error the corrupted message is not handled recursively blocking further processing), but my `DLQ` configuration is corrupted, is any ideas what can be wrong here?

### P.S.

Possible I need something like a `deserializationExceptionHandler: sendToDlq`  but I didn't detect this property in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/kafka/kafka_overview.html#_apache_kafka_binder).

Comment: stream:
      bindings:
        report-in-0:
          destination: ${kafka-conf.consume-topic-report}
          group: ${kafka-conf.group}-report
    contentType: application/json
          consumer:
            partitioned: true
            concurrency: 1
            headerMode: embeddedHeaders
            maxAttempts: 1
        report-out-0:
          destination: ${kafka-conf.produce-topic-report}
      kafka:
        bindings:
          report-in-0:
            consumer:
              enableDlq: true
              dlqPartitions: 1

Comment: @Vaibs, can you please share the doc link please and short description what i messed. or try share the fragment code, not the single line :)

Comment: Its not clear if you are using the Kafka binder, Kafka Streams binder or both. Could you set up a small sample application with a README on GH so that we can reproduce the issues you are facing?

Comment: I've updated published yml file ( the merge was partly incorrect). The [project example](https://github.com/SergiiVlasiuk/spring-boot-kafka/blob/master/kafka-stream-poc/src/main/resources/application-78107151.yml) and [steps to reproduce](https://github.com/SergiiVlasiuk/spring-boot-kafka/blob/master/kafka-stream-poc/README.md#steps-to-reproduce).

Comment: it seems that my question is quite complicated, because it took a lot of time, but still without a solution. let me know please if you need different details from my side.